# Having trouble with NSString return type in Objective-C blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

Thanks guy for help you. My problem is next. I need use AFNetworking and when request petition to server, the server is response. This result I need return in my method. The method AFNetworking use block for succes or failed. I want return the return server string (operation) in succes or failed option block.

```
- (NSString *)executeMultipart:(NSURL *)url
{
    __block NSString *strJSON;

    [_operationManager POST:[url absoluteString]parameters:_params
  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[_params objectForKey:TAG_PHOTO] name:TAG_PHOTO];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        strJSON = [operation.responseString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        return strJSON;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        strJSON = [operation.responseString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        return strJSON;
    }];
}
```

But show error:

> "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSString
>   *(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__strong, _*strong id)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation **_strong, __strong id)'"

I'm sorry if my problem is stupid, because I beginning develop with iOS. Please help me!!! Thanks you.

Comment: Why are you wanting to return a NSString* inside of a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is `async block` and you and method will return before block execute completely.
You should not return this `string` you should call some completion handler or delegate method.
Better will be you pass completion handler to method and call that completion handler where you are returning string.

Your method should be like this.

```
- (void)executeMultipart:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString*))handler
{
    __block NSString *strJSON;

    [_operationManager POST:[url absoluteString]parameters:_params
  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[_params objectForKey:TAG_PHOTO] name:TAG_PHOTO];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        strJSON = [operation.responseString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       handler(strJSON);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        strJSON = [operation.responseString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       handler(strJSON);
    }];
}
```

from the class where you are using this method you should call this method as

```
[obj executeMultipart:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSString* returnString)handler{
// code here 
// do whatever you want to with return string
}];
```

Comment: I understand that but do not ask me how I can solve. How I can resolve this problema for me. Thanks for you help.

Comment: You should now call this method and pass completion handler block as parameter. when handler will be called here your block will be run

Comment: I do it this, but show me error: "Control Reaches end of non-void function". This problem is not return none finally line code. But if I return any object then me return string "none" or nil. I return string in contains block(high Priority), but the methods AFNetworking is yes or yes use block. Show me problem detail this link, please help me and thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640102/how-manipulate-block-objective-c-in-afnetworking/21643644?noredirect=1#21643644

Comment: this method should have return type void... see my edited answer...

Comment: Thanks man. I can fixed this problem with you solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:` method wants a block that doesn't return anything.

It sounds like you're trying to return the result of an asynchronous method. This isn't generally practical. The entire point of an asynchronous method is that is doesn't happen in line with other things. You'll need to have that method take a callback of its own.