# Method with completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I've created a method in a class:

```
- (void)getTableData:(NSString *)URL withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *))handler{

__block NSDictionary *JSON;
[manager POST:urlString parameters:jsonDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

    JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    handler(JSON);
}
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"error %@",error);
          // handle failure
      }];
}
```

and call it in another class by

```
[ObjOfSecondClass getTableData:BILL withCompletionHandler:^(NSString* returnString)handler{
    }];
```

It shows Expected expression error at handler.

Comment: What do you want in your callback?

Comment: NSDictionary *JSON;

Comment: I haven't really understood your problem. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want to create a static method. Static method is defined by using `+` mark:
`+ (void)getTableData:(NSString *)URL withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *))handler;`

Comment: @iPeter - I want to get the JSON dictionary in second class.

Comment: I refered this page      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637876/having-trouble-with-nsstring-return-type-in-objective-c-blocks

Comment: change your completion handler definition to withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictonary *))handle . current it return string only.

Comment: pawan, It shows same error.

Comment: Are you getting success from the webservice call? @Lenin

Comment: it should not. post a screenshot from your xcode.

Comment: Yeahm @pawan is right, how can you pass a dictionary to a string variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an expression error because you are using it in wrong way.

Try this one in `viewDidLoad`

```
[ObjOfSecondClass getTableData:BILL withCompletionHandler:^(NSString* returnString){
}];
```

`handler` is used is block implementation to return value from where they are called.

Note - replace string to dictionary in block definition because you are getting dictionary from API not string.

[Learn block syntax](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)